# Upload pdf file with gdata docs python v3.0 with ocr

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, gdata, gdata-api

I've got the following implementation for uploading a pdf file to google docs (taken from the gdata API samples):

```
def UploadResourceSample():
  """Upload a document, and convert to Google Docs."""
  client = CreateClient()
  doc = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='document', title='My Sample Doc')

  # This is a convenient MS Word doc that we know exists
  path = _GetDataFilePath('test.0.doc')
  print 'Selected file at: %s' % path

  # Create a MediaSource, pointing to the file
  media = gdata.data.MediaSource()
  media.SetFileHandle(path, 'application/msword')

  # Pass the MediaSource when creating the new Resource
  doc = client.CreateResource(doc, media=media)
  print 'Created, and uploaded:', doc.title.text, doc.resource_id.text
```

Now I would like to perform OCR text recognition on the uploaded file. But I'm not sure how to enable the OCR recognition in gdata docs python API. So my question is:
Is there a way to enable OCR recognition using gdata python v3.0 API on a pdf file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get my pdf document OCR'ed using the following code:

```
def UploadResourceSample(filename, filepath, fullpath):
  """Upload a document, and convert to Google Docs."""
  client = CreateClient()
  doc = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type='document', title=filename)

  path = fullpath
  print 'Selected file at: %s' % path

  # Create a MediaSource, pointing to the file
  media = gdata.data.MediaSource()
  media.SetFileHandle(path, 'application/pdf')

  # Pass the MediaSource when creating the new Resource
  create_uri = gdata.docs.client.RESOURCE_UPLOAD_URI + '?ocr=true&ocr-language=de'
  doc = client.CreateResource(doc, create_uri=create_uri, media=media)
  print 'Created, and uploaded:', doc.title.text, doc.resource_id.text
```